# Minifilter: how to run application from kernel mode

Tags: kernel, driver, minifilter

Now, I'm working with minifilter in kernel-mode. I want to run an application ( system application such as: **notepad.exe**, **mspaint.exe** or an application which is made by user such as: **C# application** ...).

My questions are:

1. Can I run application from kernel?
2. If can, how should I do?

Happy new year !

Thanks all

**[EDIT]**

I create a windows service `(C#)` to communicate between them (Minifilter `(C)` and Application `(C#, C/C++)`)

1. Windows service will start app ==> Done. It will execute after get and check message from minifilter.
2. Minifilter send message to service
3. [Minifilter] Create communication port
4. [Minifilter] Send message to service after check conditions
5. [Service] Get message from this port by FilterGetMessage

   **==> How using FilterGetMessage in C#?**

**UPDATE:** I used

6. **FltSendMessage** at driver to send message to service
7. **FilterGetMessage** at service to get message from driver

**==> But the message buffer is null although the status is success (status = 0)**

```
What is not correct?
```

P/S: The message content is a file name.

Comment: it is impossible to run directly application from kernel. you should make a thread or service as doing run application, and then the thread request a kernel driver, and wait until kernel driver fire the shared event, or complete pending IRP

Comment: @reinhardv.z. Following you: I must make a service standing between minifilter driver and application. When some conditions is right, minifilter share event to service, then service start application. Is it right?
<br/> Can you give more information about minifilter driver shared event or complete pending IRP? (I'm just a newbie).
<br/><br/>Thank you very much.

Comment: maybe this article will help you .... inverted call model http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=94 good luck

Comment: @reinhardv.z. I'm using windows service to communicate between them. I could call application from windows service. How about communication between minifilter vs windows service? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Minifilter has framework to send & receive message from a usermode application. Check this api: FilterSendMessage for more information on the communication mechanism. Using this, you can send notification to a user mode app to start an application.

Comment: _The FilterSendMessage function **sends a message to** a kernel-mode minifilter_. But I want minifilter (kernel-mode) start application (Ex: C:\Program Files\Abc\def.exe)) which isn't running now. Thanks!

Comment: You need an usermode application to which the kernel mode driver passes the message when it needs to run an application.

Comment: I have:
 - (1)Minifilter (kernel-mode) -- It always run<br/><br/>
 - (2)Application with GUI (user-mode) -- It doesn't. It only run when minifilter check conditions. And It will stop automaticly after done.

Comment: I'm trying to use windows service to communicate between them.

Comment: Windows service called application. But I don't know commnunicating between minifilter vs windows service. Can you give me an advice?

Comment: In WDK, there is sample using FilterSendMessage to communicate between a minifilter & application. Check it out you will get an idea on it.